# Add string in a range creation

Tags: python

I would like to create a row in order to use it as header into a dataframe.

The format is this

```
[a0, a1, a2]
```

or without comma I am not sure what it needs to paste as hearder into the dataframe.

What I tried is this:

```
"a" + str(range(0,3))
```

but the result is this:

```
a[0, 1, 2]
```

Comment: `"[" + ", ".join("a" + str(i) for i in range(0, 3)) + "]"`

Comment: All answers work and thank you. I upvoted them all not sure which one to accept.

Answer (score 7):

Use list comprehension with `format`:

```
c = ['a{}'.format(x) for x in range(3)]
print (c)
['a0', 'a1', 'a2']
```

If want change columns names in pandas dataframe:

```
df.columns = 'a' + df.columns.astype(str)
```

Or use [`add_prefix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.add_prefix.html):

```
df = df.add_prefix('a')
```

Sample:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[2,3,4]])
df = df.add_prefix('a')
print (df)
   a0  a1  a2
0   2   3   4
```

Comment: Is there a term for doing essentially a loop in one line? If I wanted to learn more about that, what would I look up? (How you, and others, did `z(x) for x in y` instead of say `for x =1 to 3 // z(x)`)

Comment: @BruceWayne - It is callled `list comprehension`.

Answer (score 5):

```
range(0, 3)
```

returns a list like this:

```
[0, 1, 2]
```

If you wanted this to become [a0, a1, a2] you could use a list comprehension.

e.g.

```
myList = ["a" + str(val) for val in range(0, 3)]
```

If you haven't used list comprehensions, then this is just a concise way of writing

```
myList = []
for val in range(0, 3):
    myList.append("a" + str(val))
```

After this, myList will be

```
['a0', 'a1', 'a2']
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use `map`:

```
new_data = map(lambda x:"a{}".format(x), range(3))
```

Output:

```
['a0', 'a1', 'a2']
```

Or, slightly shorter:

```
new_string = ("a{} "*3).format(*range(3)).split()
```

Output:

```
['a0', 'a1', 'a2']
```

Answer (score 3):

Try to add your string `'a'` to your list in a list iteration after you create your range. For instance:

```
column_names = range(3)
column_names = ['a'+str(i) for i in x]
```

you can then use this list as your `columns` argument when you define your dataframe.

Answer (score 3):

If you're looking for shortest code, try list comprehension with [`f-strings`](https://cito.github.io/blog/f-strings/) (in Python 3.6+):

```
[f'a{i}' for i in range(3)]
```

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
header = ["a" + str(x) for x in range(0,3)]
```

Output

```
["a0","a1","a2"]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use list comprehension :

```
["a" + str(i) for i in range(0,3)]
```

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps a less concise but easier to read method would be:

```
b = []
for i in range(0, 3):  
    c = "a" + str(i)
    b.append(c)
```

Here we take an empty list and add a string with the desired letter and the value of `range()` add them together and use the `append()` method to add them to the list.